# How Android Password manager App works?

Tags: android, passwords

I have seen few password manager apps in android like lastpass.
I am also trying to build this kind of app.

How this apps are working?

**How they get access to EditText & PasswordField of third party app?**

**How they detect login screen?**

Is there any Android system api this apps using?

Please give me hint. How this things are working?

**UPDATE**

I found one useful [resource](http://www.slideshare.net/faysal.b/a-keyboard-that-manages-your-passwords-in-android) on web. But it didn't say anything about which api to use!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching lot I got the solution. It's possible to get access of EditText & PasswordField of third party app using [accessibility api](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html) we can set & get values of edittext & password field using `AccessibilityNodeInfo` & `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT`. I done this thing by using this api. To detect which app is running on screen. You have to place this line `android:packageNames="com.example"`in your `accessibility.xml` file.

Where `com.example` is package name of application for which you want to trigger your accessibility service.

Please read Docs related to accessibility service from android.developer site.

Sample **accessibility.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewFocused|typeViewClicked"
    android:packageNames="com.example"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"/>
```